# ArgumentError (Invalid argument: Instance of 'TextEditingController')

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Please help.. i'm trying to make update data page, but this error come out in this line..

```
Firestore.instance.collection('reg').add({'name':controllerName})
```

here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';


class EditList extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _EditListState createState() => _EditListState();
}

class _EditListState extends State<EditList> {
TextEditingController controllerName;


@override
void initState() { 
  controllerName = new TextEditingController();
  super.initState();

}
  var name;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Registration'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              ),
              Text('GROUP'),
              TextField(
                controller: controllerName,
                  onChanged: (String str) {
                    setState(() {
                      name= str;
                    });
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Name',
                  )),
              //paste here
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (controllerName.text.isNotEmpty) {
                    Firestore.instance.collection('reg').add({'name':controllerName}) 
                    .then((result){
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      controllerName.clear();
                    }).catchError((err) =>print(err));
                  }
                },
                child: const Text('Submit', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to put a `TextEditingController` in your database in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('reg').add({'name':controllerName})
```

should be replaced with:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('reg').add({'name':controllerName.text})
```

Also, you should probably give your `TextField` an initial value of an empty string so that it can't be null.

Comment: is correct. You can also use:
`controllerName.text ?? ""` to default to an empty string if the contents are null.

Answer (score 1):

**controllerName is not a String,**

```
controllerName.text
```

use that

Answer (score 1):

How do I add uuid inside the document? Tried adding .docs(uuid) before .add({ it's having an error.

```
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  String? uuid = " ";

  Future<void> addUser() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
      if (user == null) {
        print('User is currently signed out!');
      } else {
        uuid = user.uid;
        print(uuid);
      }
    });

    // Call the user's CollectionReference to add a new user
    return users
        .add({
          'uuid': uuid, // John Doe
          'first': firstNameController.text, // John Doe
          'middle': middleNameController.text, // Stokes and Sons
          'surname': surNameController.text // 42
        })
        .then((value) => print("User Added"))
        .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add user: $error"));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing TextEditingController will definetly cause error because it just have instance of controller but you need text data to pass to function in upper most line. Controller attached to a textfield contains many of the property along with text inside the textfield.
You need to get the text from controller and pass it to the firebase function.
The line causing error:

```js
Firestore.instance.collection('reg').add({'name':controllerName})
```

should be like this,

```js
Firestore.instance.collection('reg').add({'name':controllerName.text})
```

and will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
Firestore.instance.collection('reg').add({'name':controllerName})
```

To this line

```
Firestore.instance.collection('reg').add({'name':controllerName.text})
```

The difference is `controllerName.text`